# ASP.NET MVC: all controller values are passed null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I've added new action to my asp.net mvc application and add specific rule for it inside `RouteConfig.cs`.

But all parameters passed as `null`.

Here is my route rule:

```
routes.MapRoute(
     "toekn_submit_route",
    "{controller}/SendToken/{platform}/{token}/{uid}", 
    new { controller = "Home", action = "SendToken" }
    , new[] { "MvcApplication.Controllers" }
);
```

And here is action deceleration:

```
public JsonResult SendToken(string platform, string token, string uid) { ... }
```

I call action using this URL: `http://localhost:51650/Home/SendToken/platform/token/uid`

Comment: @RahulSingh sorry I can't understand your question. Can you explain more?

Comment: I mean you don't have placeholder for `action` like this:- `"{controller}/{action}/{platform}/{token}/{uid}"`

Comment: @RahulSingh action is hard coded in my url and defined in route parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order of how routes are added is important. First matched route wins.

Make sure that this added route is added before more general routes otherwise they would be matched by another route that doesn't populate the  placeholders as intended.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "token_submit_route",
    url: "{controller}/SendToken/{platform}/{token}/{uid}", 
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "SendToken" },
    namespaces: new[] { "MvcApplication.Controllers" }
);

//...other more general routes.

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

For example if the `Default` route was placed before the token route it would still match `http://localhost:51650/Home/SendToken/platform/token/uid`

where

```
controller = "Home", 
action = "SendToken", 
id = "platform/token/uid"
```

Comment: All the problem was that I've missed to pass uid as 3rd parameter and so this route rule was not fired.